# merging multiple csv's in R

Tags: r, csv, merge, dataframe

Hi i was merging csv downloaded from NSE Bhavcopy. different dates have different no of cols. Say in 26-12-2006 it had 998 rows & 27-12-2006 it has 1003 rows. It has 8 cols. I do the cbind to create a & b with just 2 cols, Symbol, close price. I name the col using colnames so that for merging i can merge by SYMBOL.

Questions:

1) When i use merge function with by = "SYMBOL", all = F; i was surprised to see resulting c having 1011 rows. where ever i read, merging with all = F it should become 998 rows or max 1003 rows. I also analyzed the data and found there were 5 different symbols in 27-12-2006 & 3 different symbols in 26-12-2006. So when we merge by "SYMBOL" will new symbols from both rows will be added? or it will merge only with earlier existing a row?

2) NSEmerg is a function using a for loop to read new file every time & merge with existing c file. I have about 1535 files having data from 2006 Dec till 2013 Apr. However i was not able to merge more than 12 files as it throws error vector size of 12 MB cannot be allowed. It also shows warning messages saying memory allocation of 1535 MB used up. Also at 12th file i found nrow of c to be 1508095 implying loop running infinitely. Of all the 1535 files, highest row was at 1435. Even if we add all stocks delisted, no traded on specific date, i believe it might not cross 2200 stocks. Why this shows nrow of 1.5 Million??

3) Is there any better way of merging csv? I am in stack overflow for first time else i would have attached say 10 files.

Code:

```
a <- read.csv("C://Users/home/desktop/061226.csv", stringsAsFactors = F, header = T)
b <- read.csv("C://Users/home/desktop/061227.csv", stringsAsFactors = F, header = T)
a_date <- a[2,1]
b_date <- b[2,1]
a <- cbind(a[,2],a[,6])
b <- cbind(b[,2], b[,6])
colnames(a) <- c("SYMBOL", a_date)
colnames(b) <- c("SYMBOL", b_date)
c <- merge(a,b,by = "SYMBOL", all = F)

NSEmerg <- function(x,y) {
     y_date <- y[2,1]
     y <- cbind(y[,2], y[,6])
     colnames(y) <- c("SYMBOL", y_date)
     c <- merge(c, y, by = "SYMBOL", all = F)
   }

filenames = list.files(path = "C:/Users/home/Documents/Rest data", pattern = "*csv")

for (i in 1:length(filenames)){
    y <- read.csv(filenames[i], header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
    c <- NSEmerg(c,y)
   }

write.csv(c, file = "NSE.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to `cbind` and not `rbind`? To answer your last question. First you list all the .csv files in your map:

```
listfiles <- list.files(path="C:/Users/home/desktop", pattern='\\.csv$', full.names=TRUE)
```

Next use `do.call` to read in the different csv files and combine them with `rbind`.

```
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(listfiles , read.csv))
```

Comment: the `pattern` argument is a regular expression, so you should escape the period, otherwise it means any character. And if you want to be full-proof, you should add a $ to indicate end-of-string, e.g., `pattern='\\.csv$'`.

Answer (score -1):

You'd probably be better off just using a perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe1 file1 file2 file3 ... > newfile
```

and then you can cut the columns you need out

```
cut -f1,2 -d"," newfile > result
```

Comment: I have no clue on PERL, earlier when i pasted quote it threw error saying PERL not available; Can you pl give me the exact syntax? say i have files 130425.csv, 130423.csv, 130422.csv; How to create a new file in perl with just 3 files? All the 3 files are in working directory only. When i typed your code, it throw me an error saying unexpected numeric constant in perl -pe1 130425. Sorry again i am very new to coding & R